# Settings For ffmpeg For Best VP9 Quality for Web Publishing

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, vp9

I have video in Apple ProRes 422 format which I plan to encode to Google's VP9 for publishing on the Web. The source is:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 114644 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
```

My goal is to encode it to VP9 with the best possible (reasonable) quality, almost indistinguishable from the original. The result file size is of no actual concern. Now I use the following, but the video in Chrome looks bad:

```
ffmpeg -i Source.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 4M -pix_fmt yuv420p -speed 4 -frame-parallel 0 -threads 2 -c:a libopus -b:a 320K Result.webm
```

I tried to increase `-b:v 4M` setting, the size rises, but the quality not. Also I tried [this guide](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide), but it is probably outdated and I cannot get any satisfactory result. By the way, I have latest `ffmpeg` compiled from source.

Which `ffmpeg` settings should I use?

Comment: But do you have the latest libvpx?

Comment: `libvpx-dev` is from _Debian Testing_ repository, which is now of version 1.5.0-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some experiments I found that guide I mentioned in the question is quite useful. I had success with the instructions from the *Constant Quality Recommended Settings* section, and what was need to be fine-tuned is the `-crf` setting.

After quite a lot of tests, I ended up with the `-crf 23` setting, with which the result `webm` file is of very good quality, compared to the original.

The exact `ffmpeg` commands are:

1. First pass:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i Source.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 0 -crf 15 -threads 2 -speed 4 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -an -y -f webm /dev/null
   ```
2. Second pass:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i Source.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 0 -crf 15 -threads 2 -speed 2 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -c:a libopus -b:a 320k -f webm Out.webm
   ```

For some reason, a first pass does not use all CPU cores (2 in my case), despite the `-threads 2` option, however a second uses them all.

Comment: In CRF mode, you can skip using two passes, without much cost in quality.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a 1-pass encode in speed 4, which are fast parameters but far from optimal quality.

The guide seems good, have you tried their 2-pass or constant/constrained quality settings ? Obviously, don't keep their example 1000k bitrate.

Comment: Yep, yesterday gave the guide the second try and had success. Details are in my answer.